# Laravel 8 - can't remove data

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm beginner in Laravel. When I trying to remove any row with modal it is removing but first row removing. I don't where is the problem.

**My modal is**

```
<p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</small>@if(Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->id == $user->id))<span class="icon_trash" style="color: red; float:right;" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"></span>@endif</p>
                          
                          <div class="modal modal-danger fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                  <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h4>
                                </div>
                                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('icerikDelete',$post->id) }}">
                                    @csrf
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                  <p class="text-center">
                                    Are you sure you want to delete this?
                                  </p>
                                     
                          
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No, Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Yes, Delete</button>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

**My script is:**

```
  $('#delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
          var cat_id = button.data('catid') 
          var modal = $(this)
          modal.find('.modal-body #cat_id').val(cat_id);
    })
```

Comment: Share the controller code that is doing the actual deletion

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#default{{ $post->id }}">
      Delete
  </button>
  <div class="modal fade text-left" id="default{{ $post->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1"
  aria-hidden="true">
    # YOUR FORM HERE WITH ACTION
    # FOR EXAMPLE action={{ route('posts.delete', ['post' => $post->id]) }}
  </div>
```

Just Pass your Post ID to your HTML Modal, in data-target and on ID modal itself. i tested without script and it works